# Select bigger articles among two wikipedias

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

Using "Quarry" from Wmflabs (https://quarry.wmflabs.org/).

As I understand this is MySQL.

How can I select all articles from german wiki, which are bigger by size, than articles in enwiki?

Here is the code, I use. I need the de_len, but I don't know how to get it.

```
USE enwiki_p;

SELECT 
        page_title en_title,
        page_len en_len,
        ll.ll_title as de_title
FROM page
JOIN langlinks ll
    ON ll_from = page_id
WHERE page_namespace = 0
GROUP BY page_id  
HAVING max(CASE ll_lang  WHEN 'de' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0  
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Can you explain what you tried and where exactly you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with minimum three tables from two databases to get properly page sizes of corresponing articles (pages) from two wikis, plus related interlanguage links for relationship, for a good comparison.
A solution would be this:

```
SELECT 
       enp.page_title as en_title,
       enp.page_len as en_len,
       dep.page_title as de_title,
       dep.page_len as de_len        
FROM enwiki_p.page enp
JOIN enwiki_p.langlinks enll
  ON enll.ll_from = enp.page_id and ll_lang="de"
JOIN dewiki_p.page dep
  ON enll.ll_title = REPLACE(dep.page_title, '_', ' ')
WHERE enp.page_namespace = 0 and enp.page_is_redirect = 0 
  AND dep.page_namespace = 0 and dep.page_is_redirect = 0
GROUP BY enp.page_id  
HAVING dep.page_len > enp.page_len
ORDER BY dep.page_len DESC  
LIMIT 100
```